# Bulma responsive classes not applying

Tags: css, sass, bulma

Any responsive classes I use like m-0-tablet are applying before their non-responsive counter parts in Bulma.

I'm also using gulp purge CSS if that helps.

[image: Styles]

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is add `cdn css bulma` to make it work